# Starting vmware in headless mode

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, headless

I have a centos vm and I was wondering if there is a way to turn that vm into headless mode.

I found this information on different site

```
If you want to run a headless VM under VMPlayer simply add the following to your vmware preferences file ($HOME/.vmware/preferences):

pref.vmplayer.exit.vmAction = "disconnect"
```

but I couldn't find the $HOME/.vmware/preferences directory.

Comment: same problem with me !

Answer (score 1):

You can start a VM in headless mode by using [`vmrun`](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Fusion/13/com.vmware.fusion.using.doc/GUID-24F54E24-EFB0-4E94-8A07-2AD791F0E497.html) with the `nogui` flag:

```
vmrun start <PATH TO VM> nogui
```

Similarly, to later suspend machine:

```
vmrun suspend <PATH TO VM>
```

To see a list of running VMs:

```
vmrun list
```

Answer (score -1):

### **Assuming your VM Host is Windows**

**Short answer:**

Edit this file: `%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Roaming\VMWare\preferences.ini`

---

**Slightly longer answer:**

If you haven't set Hidden Folders as visible in Windows File Explorer, you may have trouble finding the `AppData` folder.

**To view Hidden Folders:**

1. Open Windows Explorer (the folder icon)
2. Select the view tab
3. [tick the box next to Hidden items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDNtR.png)

**Add the new setting:**

1. Shut down any running VMs and close VMWare Player
2. Open your home folder:

   - Press `WINKEY + R`
   - Type `%HOMEPATH%` in the box and hit `[ENTER]`
3. Open `AppData` -> `Roaming` -> `VMware`

   - If you're in the right place, you should see [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6fL9.png)
4. Right click `preferences.ini` and choose `Edit`
5. Add `pref.vmplayer.exit.vmAction = "disconnect"` on a new line at the bottom.
6. Save and close. Then start VMWare.
7. If everything went right, you should be able to close a running VM window and it will continue on in the background.

**note:** This didn't actually cause the intended effect for me under VMWare Player 15.5.1 - YMMV